# Why Search a 2D Matrix Show result cannot pass？

Tags: search

Question:
Write an efficient algorithm that searches for a value in an m x n matrix.

This matrix has the following properties:

Integers in each row are sorted from left to right.
The first integer of each row is greater than the last integer of the previous row.

```
class Solution {
public:
/**
 * @param matrix, a list of lists of integers
 * @param target, an integer
 * @return a boolean, indicate whether matrix contains target
 */
bool searchMatrix(vector<vector<int> > &matrix, int target) {

    bool flag = false; 
    int mbegin = 0, mend = matrix.size() - 1;
    // target in matrix?
    while (mbegin <= mend) {

        int mmid = (mbegin + mend) / 2;
        vector<int> sub = matrix[mmid];
        int begin = 0, end = sub.size() - 1;

        // target in sub?
        if (sub[0] <= target && target <= sub[end]) {
            while(begin <= end) {
                int mid = (begin + end) / 2;

                if (sub[mid] == target) {
                    flag = true;
                    return flag;
                }
                else if (sub[mid] < target) {
                    begin = mid + 1;
                }
                else {
                    end = mid - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (sub[end] < target) {
            mbegin = mmid + 1;
        }
        else{
            mend = mmid - 1;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
};
```

input

`[[1,5,9,13,18,25,28,33,39,43,44,51,55,56,63,68,73,77,80],[100,117,141,164,181,199,218,241,265,285,310,326,341,354,370,380,397,408,420],[433,453,475,494,506,518,536,550,568,585,609,626,651,662,676,698,716,729,746],[766,791,809,829,844,869,894,916,930,947,967,981,992,1012,1036,1059,1083,1099,1116],[1137,1150,1163,1177,1199,1215,1231,1243,1268,1283,1304,1326,1344,1362,1387,1408,1428,1438,1461],[1485,1499,1521,1546,1566,1584,1606,1622,1637,1656,1681,1705,1726,1744,1758,1779,1802,1827,1842]]`

1084

Expected
false

but there are nothing showed up! why?

Comment: you should add your code and describe the problem directly on SO

Comment: Thanks! I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account the two properties, here are the optimizations possible for your algorithm:

- You can skip searching rows that begin with a number greater than the one you seek.
- In each row, when you reach a number greater than the one you seek, you can stop searching.

You have to look in all rows that can't be excluded by these criteria.  The specification doesn't if you must find all occurences. It also doesn't tell if the value can be missing, if it is guaranteed to occur once or if it can occur multiple times.

With `int mmid = (mbegin + mend) / 2;`, it looks as if you are trying to do a binary search.